# How to check if an instance update has been saved?

Tags: sequelize.js

With `sqeuelizejs 6.5` in `nodes 14.x`, for a model instance, is there way to check if the instance has been saved/updated (similar to model.saved() in ruby ORM)? Here is a code example:

```
let art = await Artwork.findByPk(req.body.id);  //art is an instance of Artwork model
if (!art) return false;

//do some update with instance art, such as : 
//art.name = "a new name";
//art.description = "a new description";
//await art.save();

//.....some code here

if (art.saved()) {. //<<==is there art.saved()/art.updated() to check if the instance update has been saved?
  //do something
} else {
  //if art not updated, do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(art.changed()) { // need save
} else {
  // no updated
}
```